# require is not defined while including template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

```
Vue.extend('nav-bar', {
    template: require('../views/navbar.html')
})
```

I am creating a template using an external html file but it says require is not defined.

Comment: You can't do it like that. require() is for .js or .vue (with a transpiller) files only.

Comment: If you really want to do that this way, rename navbar.html to navbar.js, and add as first line: `module.exports = \`` and as last line `\`;`. But that's a very bad idea. Consider using https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html instead.

Comment: But I don't want all the html in a single page. I want to separate them out in multiple files in the form of templates. How can I use .vue file ? I am not using any front-end framework. Using plain html,js.

Comment: Its better your read about single file components and then look at https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli and start with scaffolding.

Comment: Vue is missing few things. I want  vuex-persistentdata cdn link but unable to find it on google.

Comment: `$.ajax('{url:../views/navbar.html', async:false}),responseText` will work in this case, although it is not recommended.